# Objc get all properties of class fails

Tags: ios, objective-c, corespotlight

I want to create a CSSearchableItem with a attributeSet of ALL the attributes available.

To do so, I am trying to get all of the properties of the CSSearchableItemAttributeSet class in the following way:

```
NSMutableArray * allPropertyNames(Class c)
{
    unsigned count;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([CSSearchableItemAttributeSet class], &count);

    NSMutableArray *rv = [NSMutableArray array];

    unsigned i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];
        [rv addObject:name];
    }

    free(properties);

    return rv;
}
```

The problem is I am getting the following result:

```
HTMLContentDataNoCopy,
textContentNoCopy,
accountType,
textSelected,
subtitle,
userTags,
albumPersistentID,
adamID,
extendedContentRating,
fileIdentifier,
parentFileIdentifier,
filename,
documentIdentifier,
dataOwnerType,
existingThread,
partiallyDownloaded,
queryResultMatchedFields,
uniqueIdentifier,
bundleID,
protectionClass,
expirationDate,
userActivityType,
queryResultRelevance,
applicationName,
contentSnippet,
relatedAppBundleIdentifier,
mailAttachmentNames,
mailAttachmentTypes,
mailAttachmentKinds,
mailDateReceived,
mailDateLastViewed,
mailFlagged,
mailFlagColor,
mailRead,
mailRepliedTo,
mailPriority,
mailGMailLabels,
mailMessageID,
mailCategory,
mailConversationID,
readerView,
textContentDataSource,
fileProviderID,
fileItemID,
parentFileItemID,
ownerName,
ownerIdentifier,
lastEditorName,
lastEditorIdentifier,
fileProviderDomaindentifier,
fileProviderUserInfoKeys,
fileProviderUserInfoValues,
trashed,
shared,
uploaded,
uploading,
uploadError,
downloading,
downloadError,
extraData,
favoriteRank,
subItemCount,
sharedItemCurrentUserRole,
versionIdentifier,
downloadingStatus,
lastApplicationLaunchedDate,
isPlaceholder,
mutableAttributes,
customAttributes,
attributes,
searchableItemFlags,
decoder,
contentDecoder,
codedAttributes,
codedCustomAttributes,
contentObj,
hasCodedCustomAttributes
```

None of those are the properties I was looking for.

Does anyone know how to get this?

Comment: What properties where you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

That does appear to be the list of properties declared on the `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` class.   What is unexpected?

---

While Objective-C has introspection features, said features are not designed to be used at runtime to deduce or subdivide capabilities of classes in this fashion.

I.e. introspection driven programming is largely discouraged save for some very specific examples like delegation.

In this case, you'll likely find success in either adopting CoreData's formal modeling capabilities (or a similar solution) or creating a class method that contains a list of properties that you want to advertise.

Overall, though, your code is likely to be less bug prone if you generally use relatively static call sites (i.e. [someObj myProperty]) as opposed to trying to abstract away.